# Oracle SQL - selecionar apenas clientes com mais de um pedido, listando itens de duas tabelas ID, EMAIL e ID_ORDER

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho duas tabelas:

```
table CUSTOMERS
-----------------------------------
ID_ |   EMAIL
01  |   JOHN@GMAIL.COM
02  |   MARY@HOTMAIL.COM
03  |   PAUL@LIVE.COM


table ORDERS
----------------------------------------------
ID  |   ID_ORDER    |   SKU
01  |   0101        |   123
01  |   0101        |   456
01  |   0102        |   789
02  |   0201        |   124
02  |   0201        |   562
03  |   0301        |   896
```

Preciso selecionar os clientes com mais de um pedido apenas, trazendo no relatório ID, EMAIL da tabela CUSTOMERS e ID_ORDER da tabela ORDERS. Ou seja, o resultado deveria ser:

```
ID  |   EMAIL       |   ID_ORDER

01  |   JOHN@GMAIL.COM  |   0101
01  |   JOHN@GMAIL.COM  |   0102
```

Já tentei de diversas formas, e não consegui o resultado necessário.

Comment: Dica : Use uma subquery , pesquise por EXISTS

Comment: A cláusula HAVING pode ser de grande valia.

Comment: A segunda linha do resultado não deveria ser: 02  |   MARY@HOTMAIL.COM  |   0201 ? Ou eu não entendi o relacionamento entre as tabelas?

Comment: Precisava listar os clientes com mais de 1 pedido, no caso só havia 1, por isso uma linha por pedido.

Consegui resolver de duas formas:

SELECT DISTINCT
c.ID_, c.EMAIL, o.ID_ORDER
FROM CUSTOMERS c INNER JOIN ORDERS o
ON o.ID = c.ID_
WHERE c.ID_ IN (
SELECT ID
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID_ORDER) > 1
)

OU 

SELECT DISTINCT
c.ID_, c.EMAIL, o.ID_ORDER
FROM (
SELECT ID
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID_ORDER) > 1
) g
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS c ON c.ID_ = g.ID
INNER JOIN ORDERS o ON o.ID = c.ID_


Obrigado a vcs.

Answer (score 0):

Faça a junção das tabelas e pegue apenas os registros que tiverem uma quantidade de pedidos maior que 1.

```
SELECT c.ID, c.EMAIL, o.ID_ORDERS, COUNT(o.ID_ORDER) 
    FROM CUSTOMERS c INNER JOIN ORDERS o ON (c.ID = o.ID) 
    GROUP BY c.ID, c.EMAIL, o.ID_ORDERS 
    HAVING COUNT(o.ID_ORDER) > 1;
```